# How do Laravel route groups work under the hood?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, routes, anonymous-function

I was wondering how is this working under the hood:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'parent'], function() {
    Route::get('/child', 'MyController@myMethod');
});
```

I don't understand how is Laravel associating the routes definitions in the anonymous function to the parent group.

Something like **this would have made much more sense**:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'parent'], function($group) {
    $group->get('/child', 'MyController@myMethod');
});
```

I tried diving into what happens under the hood through a debugger, and I noticed that in `Illuminate\Routing\Router.php` this happens:

```php
protected function loadRoutes($routes)
{
    if ($routes instanceof Closure) {
        $routes($this);
    } else {
        (new RouteFileRegistrar($this))->register($routes);
    }
}
```

The anonymous function that contains our routes definitions is called and `$this` gets passed to it, altho our anonymous function doesn't accept any argument, so why passing $this to it?

Comment: laravel keeps track of the 'stack' of group definitions ... everything is registered linearly so it knows what groups are 'open' at the time a route is registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route groups are a concept and they are used for cascading configuration. The way Laravel knows what configuration to apply to the routes in a "group" is because it keeps a stack of all the groups that are open so it can apply to the routes. You could just load a route file into the group which doesn't involve any closures.

Since there is a stack of the current configuration any route definition at that point will have that configuration. Before the `group` call finishes executing it pops the current configuration off of the stack (which conceptually closes the group since that configuration doesn't exist on the stack any longer so it won't be applied to any further defined routes).

Any call to define a route at any time will check to see if there is a group stack and cascade the configuration and apply it if needed. You could add information to the group stack yourself without calling `group` and then every route you define after that will have that configuration regardless of if it was defined in a route group or not.

The comment from the `group` method of `Illuminate\Routing\Router`:

> Once we have updated the group stack, we'll load the provided routes and merge in the group's attributes when the routes are created. After we have created the routes, we will pop the attributes off the stack.

Comment: Ok, so basically what you're saying is that when I call the `group` method, there is some sort of flag that says to take all the next routes and "save" them a sub-routes of this group, then `$routes($this)` gets called and at the end the flag gets resetted, right?  This makes sense, but then why is $this getting passed to $routes? Is that just so you can use that class in the anonymous function (?).

Also: in order for this logic to work, the RouteRegistrar should make use of the singleton pattern, right?